# Problem building project in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

While building a project in Eclipse I got the following output:

```
make all 

Building file: ../Source/gettimeofday.c

Invoking: GCC C Compiler

gcc -I"/root/Desktop/Eclipse/openwsman/Header" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -

MF"Source/gettimeofday.d" -MT"Source/gettimeofday.d" -o"Source/gettimeofday.o" "../Source/gettimeofday.c"

../Source/gettimeofday.c:38: warning: ‘struct timezone’ declared inside parameter list

../Source/gettimeofday.c:38: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not
 what you want

../Source/gettimeofday.c: In function ‘gettimeofday’:

../Source/gettimeofday.c:41: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

../Source/gettimeofday.c:41: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

make: *** [Source/gettimeofday.o] Error 1
```

The problematic line is:

```
int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tzp)
```

This function is declared in the header file.

Can you help me?

Comment: can you paste the code around line 41 from gettimeofday.c. Above line is declaration of method and it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

GCC complains that `struct timezone` is undeclared. A few lines down in the file it complains about dereferencing a pointer to an incomplete type. I suspect that `gettimeofday.c:41` uses the `tzp` argument. Did you include a declaration for `struct timezone`? On my system, it is declared in `/usr/include/linux/time.h`.